# Is it possible to programatically control Apache httpd on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, apache2

I would like to (preferably using Python) programmatically control Apache httpd on Windows. That is, stop and start the service, and ideally add/remove/stop/start individual sites.

I haven't found any existing libraries that do this. Is this a nonsensical endeavor (and if so, why)?

Or, is it possible to do this from the command line, and therefore just a matter of making the appropriate command line calls from within my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting and stopping services has been implemented by many libraries, for example see here:

http://www.icodeguru.com/WebServer/Python-Programming-on-Win32/ch18.htm

Controlling individual websites (VirtualHosts) heavily depends on the configuration file layout.
For example, on Debian, a specific directory structure has been devised (`/etc/apache2/sites-available`, `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`...) and specific scripts control file copies to the "enabled" directory (`a2ensite`, `a2dissite`).

Such layout does not exist in the default Windows Apache distribution, so it is really up to you to replicate it and create the corresponding scripts or apis. This is the solution I recommend.

Another approach would be to parse the apache configuration directly and comment-out specific sections as needed, but this is risky because any error in editing these files might keep apache from restarting altogether.